# How to transplant a feature (in a topic branch) to another branch?

Tags: git, version-control

Say I have 2 parallel long lived branches: `master` and `experimental`. And I do some work in a topic branch off of `experimental`, and I do this for a couple features (`feature1`, `feature2`, `feature3`). How would I transplant the work done in `feature2` onto `master`?

My initial repository:

```
  master
    |
A-B-C
 \                              
  D-E       I       L           P
     \     / \     / \         /|
      F-G-H   \   /   \       / |
          |    J-K     \     / experimental
      feature1   |      M-N-O
              feature2      |
                         feature3
```

My desired repository:

```
                                   master
                                     |
A-B-C-----------------------------J'-K'
 \                              
  D-E       I       L           P
     \     / \     / \         /|
      F-G-H   \   /   \       / |
          |    J-K     \     / experimental
      feature1   |      M-N-O
              feature2      |
                         feature3
```

One way I can think of doing it is `git checkout master; git cherry-pick J K` but that's error prone and the topic branch might have many different commits.

I would expect it to work something like `git checkout master; git <transplant-commits-in-topic-branch-onto-current-branch> feature2`, but all of the rebasing commands I'm familiar with transplant all the diffs from the common ancestor (in this case `A`), I want to transplant just the diffs between `I` and `K`, and not mess with commit hashes.

A bit of context: I'm working on a codebase which was forked off of an original, however I'd like to contribute certain features back. And I develop all the new features in topic branches which I then merge back into my master.

Comment: Any particular reason this was tagged as `svn`? Sounds like a purely Git-related question to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're just trying to move `feature2` onto `master`, and 'I' and 'K' don't depend on changes made in `feature1`, you can transplant it with:

```
git rebase --onto master feature1 feature2
```

That syntax reads, loosely, as "Rebase `feature2` onto `master`. It's original upstream was `feature1`."

Then if you merge `feature2` into `master`, it'll be a fast-forward merge.

If, however, `feature2` depends on changes in `feature1` that won't be on `master`, the whole situation gets much more complicated, and what you want to do depends entirely on your workflow and how you relate to the parent project. Cherry-picking would work... so long as you're willing to make later merges of your feature branches complicated against the origin's master. Or you could rebase all of your branches so that `feature2` applies cleanly against `master`, or... about a dozen other methods. It really depends on your long term plan for these branches. In general, cut `feature2` (and `feature3` and so on) off `master` if you can help it. It'll save you a lot of trouble down the line.